# regex to export a domain name from a link

Tags: javascript, regex

I went through the list of questions with a same titles, but none of them answered my question so I am forced to create a new one.

I am trying to get a domain name form a string using regex in js. Here are some examples:

1. www.demo.com
2. http://demo.co.uk/
3. https://demo.com/foo.html?q=bar
4. https://www.demo.com/foo.html?q=bar
5. http://demo.co.uk/foo.html?q=bar
6. http://www.demo.com/foo.html?q=bar
7. www.demo.com.co
8. demo.com
9. demo.co.uk

all of the above should return 'demo'

my current regex looks like this

```
(\/{2}www\.|\/{2}|www\.)([^\...\.?]+)\.
```

It passes all cases but the last one, I tired edding another option as \0, but it is still does not match the last test.

You can view it matching most of them [here](http://regexr.com/3bf4i)

Comment: Does `([^.\s/]+)\.[^.\s]+(?:/|$)` suffice for your needs?

Comment: if you use your regex on the link I provided you can see that it does not match www.demo.com and www.demo.com.co

Comment: Right.  `([^.\s/]+)\.[^.\s]+(?:\/|$|\s)`, then.

Comment: The reason I ask is because you aren't too clear on exactly what your rules are.  For instance, for `demo.co.uk`, do you expect the domain to be `co`, `demo.co`, or just plain `demo`?

Comment: you probablyt have not tested it, because it matches the domain untill the first character of the next link, also I updated the question with your example.

Comment: I've tested it.  Yes, it matches that much, but it's the value of the first group that has just the domain part of the match.  If you want it to only match on the domain, that could be done too with a look-ahead, you didn't specify that either.  I was just basing it on the way that you had constructed your example.

Comment: Using look-ahead to only match on the domain would look like this: `[^.\s/]+(?=\.[^.\s/]+(?:\/|$|\s))`

Comment: thank you, but your last expressions matches 'co' in www.demo.co.uk

Comment: As I said before, that's why I'm asking in a comment rather than writing an answer.  You haven't been clear about what you want.  What *do* you want it to capture in that case?

Comment: As you can see from the examples in my question I have http://demo.co.uk and demo.co.uk and for both I want to match demo, everything what you will type after www in the url bar and before the first dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your regex:

```
(^|www|http://|https://)+(\.)?(.+?)\.
```

**Explanation:**

`(^|www|http://|https://)` - Match any of `www`, `http://`, `https://` or none 
(hence the `^`)

`(\.)?` Maybe there is a dot (if it starts with `www`)

`(.+?)\.` - Get all characters (**the domain**) until the next dot.

Use (`$3`) to get the domain.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/3bf4l)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:([^:\/\s.]+)\.)?(([^:\/\s]+))(((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?)?$


^(?:(https?):\/\/)? http://
(?:([^:\/\s.]+)\.)? subdomain.
(([^:\/\s]+))       domain.com
(((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?)?$ remaining
```

http://regexr.com/3bf87